Spring Webflux over HTTP: is my expectation of backpressure logic correct?
Problem statement
I have a question about expected behavior on a scenario where a http consumer of a REST WebFlux endpoint is slow.
I have a http consumer which calls API (java spring boot) that streams data using WebFlux. Consumer should keep the connection alive, and keep reading the data.
API streams high frequency data (4k events/sec). 1 event has 120 bytes.
We do realize that consumer may be slow, and we have a backpressure configured to drop data on such situation.
We would expect that in that case:

consumer should still be getting the data, however with a slower rate
there should be no situation that consumer should not be getting data any more (of course assuming that consumer is not blocked)

But what happens is that, there are periods that all works well (happy path, no back pressure kicks in). But there are periods where we see drops of messages. And that can be expected. But what is not expected is that as soon as we observer drops, then from that moment no more data is emitted to the client (observed by the fact that client does not get any more data). Client has to be disconnected and connect again to get back on the stream.
Whereas, we would expect that drops could occur, but the client should still be getting some data and maybe eventually the drops would stop since the backpressure buffer would be drained. Hence we would expect no reconnection is necessary to recover from that.
We thought that maybe this is something on the wire between the client and server, but we tested it hitting API directly (bypassing any reverse proxies), and we observe the same. So potentially this is caused inside REST API.
Based on the reading so far, we know that the backpressure in Webflux (on top of http) may not be ideal, but still we would think that when backpressure kicks in, we should not have to reconnect.
So maybe:

we have our code wrong or some config is missing/wrong
maybe latest versions of relevant libraries does not have such behavior
there is simply an explanation for such behavior and we have to accept it

any direction here appreciated.
Additional details
API response headers
I assume client implementation does not matter.
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json
< traceid: 0d5164d9c5771f1d
< Expires: Thu, 07 Nov 2024 13:33:55 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Thu, 07 Nov 2024 13:33:55 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Connection: Transfer-Encoding
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

API controller
   static final int BACKPRESSURE_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE = 8_000;

   @GetMapping(value = "/streaming")
   public Flux<?> streaming() {
      return dataStream.doFirst(() -> log.info("Streaming started"))
            .doOnNext(event -> counter.increment())
            .onBackpressureBuffer(BACKPRESSURE_BUFFER_MAX_SIZE, () -> droppedCounter.increment(), BufferOverflowStrategy.DROP_OLDEST)
            .doOnError(throwable -> log.error("Streaming error", throwable))
            .doFinally(signalType -> {
               log.info("Streaming finished. signalType={}", signalType);
            });
   }

Data stream setup during app startup
After that, sinks are populated using tryEmitNext() method inside a consumer that digests messages coming from a remote server over tcp.
     var SCHEDULER = Schedulers.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20));

      var sink1 = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(10_000);
      var sink2 = Sinks.many().multicast().onBackpressureBuffer(10_000);

      var heartbeatStream =
            Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                  .map(sequence -> new HeartbeatResponse(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()));

      var dataStream = Flux.merge(
                  sink1.asFlux(),
                  sink2.asFlux(),
                  heartbeatStream)
            .publishOn(SCHEDULER)
            .share();

      // dummy subscription done in @PostConstruct
      dataStream.subscribe(message -> log.debug("Data received: {}", message));

Libraries



lib
version




spring boot
2.7.18


spring webflux
5.3.31


projectreactor core
3.6.2


projectreactor netty
1.1.15


netty
4.1.101



